# SQL QUERY to Start Numbering Row_ID Everytime a Unique number Is Found

Tags: sql-server

is there any possible way to get a unique id for similar kind of number for example

```
H_ID       ROW_ID

1            1

1            2

1            3

2            1

2            2

3            1

3            2
```

AS SHOWN 1 IS REPEATED 3 TIMES SO NUMBERS ARE 1,2,3 AND THEN AGAIN STARTS WITH 1

Comment: Simple rownumber will work

    `select h,row_number() over (partition by h order by h) as row_id
    from
    table`

Comment: Have you tried `ROW_NUMBER()`? SQL Server has many [ranking and windowing functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) that make calculating row numbers, percentiles or finding gaps *very* easy.

Comment: SQL Server's ranking and windowing functions come as a pleasant surprise if someone has only worked with the only mainstream database without such functions. No need to downvote for this

Answer (score 0):

Try it's

```
declare @table table (h_id int)


insert into @table
select 1
insert into @table
select 1
insert into @table
select 1
insert into @table
select 2
insert into @table
select 2
insert into @table
select 3
insert into @table
select 3


select h_id,d 
from (select row_number() over(partition by h_id order by h_id ) as d,*
from @table) as source
```

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() window function

```
CREATE TABLE #ROW_TEST
(

H_ID    INT

)

INSERT INTO #ROW_TEST 
SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 
1  
UNION  ALL SELECT 
1
UNION  ALL SELECT 
2
UNION  ALL SELECT 
2
UNION  ALL SELECT 
3
UNION  ALL SELECT 
3

SELECT H_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY H_ID ORDER BY H_ID)  FROM #ROW_TEST
```